# Changing Permalinks format causes various issues

Tags: php, wordpress

I've installed Wordpress and the default permalink format is "/index.php/post-name".  I want to change it to "/post-name", so the URL would be "domain.com/blog/" instead of "domain.com/index.php/blog" but this is causing some strange issues. I've seen other posts on Stackoverflow with the same issue but couldn't find an exact response.

When the permalink is set to "/index.php/post-name" everything seems to be working fine. When I change it to "/post-name" is start receiving the error

> Publishing failed. Error message: The response is not a valid JSON
>   response.

Interestingly, when looking in the developer tools, that when I try to publish the page with "/index.php/post-name" the request is sent to **hxxps://domain.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/post_tag?context=edit&_locale=user** but when I try to do it with "/post-name" the request is sent to **hxxps://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/[[POST ID]]?_locale=user** which returns a 404.

My .htaccess is as follows, after trying to follow advice from other answers:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Beforehand it was:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

doing **a2enmod retwrite** returns the status "Module rewrite already enabled".
I've installed Classic Editor plugin which seems to publish, but then trying to access the file returns 404.

My environment is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.
Any assistance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: are you using apache or nginx?

Comment: I am using Apache

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - had to change **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** from **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All**.